# Cassandra can't start with an old backup of /var/lib/cassandra

Tags: backup, cassandra

I have an old Cassandra backup of `/var/lib/cassandra` on an external drive and I want to setup a new database with this backup.

I install the same Cassandra version as then and in the yaml file I changed the `data_file_directories` paths into the new ones (external drive paths) but nothing.

Any idea on how to fix it or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! A friendly note on how to ask good questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Hey Erick! Thanks for the comment. I will try to express it better the next time and be more informative.

Comment: What does "... but nothing" mean? You'll need to post the full error message + full stack trace + C* version. 

Answer (score 0):

Try running a `nodetool refresh` on each node and then restart the cluster.

If that doesn't do it, check the `logs/system.log` file and verify that it is indeed reading from the right directory.

Comment: Hey Aaron! i can't run nodetool refresh because Cassandra is not <<up>>. The logs i got from system.log and debug.log are the same and the are about the .yaml file
I created a new default .yaml file but still i got problems....i am trying a new solution right now do i will post the results later.